# Handling authorization token in next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a next.js app where we have some functionalities that require authorization. When using CRA, I simply used to store the token in a config.js file and import, use and update the token wherever I needed to. here's the code for my config file:

```
export const config = {
  "token" : window.localStorage.getItem('token')
};
```

however, in next.js we cannot use "window" since it's undefined in ssr. Other than using react context or redux, is there an easier and more simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to store `token` in `cookie` hence you can use `context.req.headers.cookie` to acquire `token` in server-side.